# How can I obtain the names of the Windows lockscreen "Spotlight" locations?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, batch-file, script

I already have a little batch file that I run every so often when I see a photo I like on the Windows lockscreen, but it would be nice to be able to remember where it was taken (you know how in the corner how it tells you). Either putting it into the file name itself or maybe in the "comments" section of the photo metadata is fine. I'd just like to remember because maybe some day I'd like to actually visit that place. Apparently Microsoft didn't think people like going to pretty places.

Anyway, here's what I've got so far.

```
:: Batch script, which copies larger "Like what you see" 
:: pictures to %userprofile%\Pictures\Saved Pictures\ and opens it in explorer
cd /D %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets
mkdir "%userprofile%\Pictures\Saved Pictures\" 1>nul 2>&1
for /r ".\" %%F in (*) do @if %%~zF geq 35000 copy "%%F" "%userprofile%\Pictures\Saved Pictures\*.jpg"
explorer "%userprofile%\Pictures\Saved Pictures\"
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: If you go to your lock screen, in the top-right corner it gives you more info about the photo. So, for instance, maybe it's showing a photo of the NYC skyline and I (for some strange considering I live 30 or so miles away) reason didn't know where it was, I can always hover over that top-right and it will tell me it's the NYC skyline. I want to add that information to the photos I'm saving in my script so that I know for future reference. I'm a big traveler and I'm always looking for new and interesting places to visit, the Spotlight locations help me get ideas if I know where they are.